# ¿Cómo puedo manterner los datos guardados en un datagridview?

Tags: c#

Hola compañeros fijese que tengo un problema con un programa que estoy trabajando en C# les comento:

Tengo tres forms inicio, ventas y almacen el problema que tengo es que cuando me traslado de un form al inicio y vuelvo al form anterior se me borran los datos que guardo en el datagridview.

Este es el código que tengo para trasladarme al inicio.

```
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 inicio = new Form1();
            inicio.Show();

        }
```

Comment: El problema es claro: Estas creando una nueva instancia de tu clase `Form1` una nueva instancia no tiene ni referencia la misma informacion de la instancia anterior, en tu caso el formulario que tiene los datos.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es invocar el método `Show()` pero de la instancia inicial e `Form1` , la que tiene los valores que no deseas perder